# event.preventDefault() у дочерних элементов

Tags: javascript

```js
jQuery('.hidden_menu .menu-item-27 a').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (jQuery('.sub-menu').css('display') == 'none') {
    jQuery('.sub-menu').css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    jQuery('.sub-menu').css('display', 'none');
  }
  if (jQuery('.sub-menu').css('display') == 'block') {
    jQuery('nav .hidden_menu').css('margin-bottom', 665 + 'px');
  } else {
    jQuery('nav .hidden_menu').css('margin-bottom', 400 + 'px');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="order-sm-1">
  <div id="nav-icon3" class="">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul class="hidden_menu" ">
    <div class="menu-menu-1-container ">
        <ul id="primary-menu-hidden " class="menu ">
            <li id="menu-item-23 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-23 "><a href=" ">Главная</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-27 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-10 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-27 "><a href=" ">Меню2</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu ">
                        <li id="menu-item-163 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-163 "><a href=" ">Подменю1</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-164 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-164 "><a href=" ">Подменю2</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-165 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-165 "><a href=" ">Подменю3</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-166 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-166 "><a href=" ">Подменю4</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-167 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-167 "><a href=" ">Подменю5</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-168 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-168 "><a href=" ">Подменю6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li id="menu-item-29 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29 "><a href=" ">Меню3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-28 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28 "><a href=" ">Меню4</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-30 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30 "><a href=" ">Меню5</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-26 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26 "><a href=" ">Меню6</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-24 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24 "><a href=" ">Меню7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Вопрос: как сделать кликабельным выпадающее меню. На данный момент при клике на любом пункте выпадающего меню происходит "сворачивание" sub-menu. А так же отменить event.preventDefault() у дочерних элементов.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `closest` - сделайте проверку, если клик на меню, значит не сворачиваем.

Comment: [это делается вот так](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/intro#ostanovka-vsplytiya)

Comment: Вопрос переоткрыл, теперь вы можете написать на него ответ)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ай-ай-ай, не надо так :-) верни как было

Comment: @Grundy, ТС попросил открыть, говоря, что вопрос не совсем дубль и он хочет ответ написать) По крайней мере в списке связанных вопросов ваша ссылка осталась)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, он написал, можешь обратно закрывать, проблема та же самая - он вместо одного конкретного элемента выбирал все на странице. и решение в итоге то же самое опубликовал

Comment: @Grundy, я в теме не разбираюсь, но поверю вам) Вопрос закрыл обратно)

Comment: @Grundy, тема, на которую вы меня послали - отвечает лишь на половину вопроса, вторая часть вопроса оставалась без ответа.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а не :-D похоже все-таки не дубль :-D вернее дубль но на другой вопрос. Вместо preventDefault надо было stopPropagation просто использовать :-)

Comment: @Devergence, сейчас добавлю второй вопрос в дубликат

Comment: @Grundy, вах, что ж так сложно то всё)

Comment: @Grundy так можно все темы закрыть как дубликаты, по сути

Comment: @Devergence, именно этим и нужно заниматься :-)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, это javascript, детка :-D

Comment: @АлександрБелинский. добавил еще одну ссылку на дубликат, вторая часть ответа как раз твой случай

Comment: @Grundy теперь бы понять как связана статья про всплытие, нерабочий js у человека и мое обычное wp меню

Comment: @Devergence, код-то один и тот же: вложенные ul, и закрытие всех при клике на внутренний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```js
   jQuery('.hidden_menu .menu-item-27').on('click', 'a', function() {

if (jQuery(event.target.parentNode).parent().hasClass('sub-menu')) {
    event.stopPropagation();
} else {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (jQuery('.sub-menu').css('display') == 'none') {
        jQuery('.sub-menu').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        jQuery('.sub-menu').css('display', 'none');
    }
    if (jQuery('.sub-menu').css('display') == 'block') {
        jQuery('nav .hidden_menu').css('margin-bottom', 665 + 'px');
    } else {
        jQuery('nav .hidden_menu').css('margin-bottom', 400 + 'px');
    }
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="order-sm-1">
  <div id="nav-icon3" class="">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul class="hidden_menu" ">
    <div class="menu-menu-1-container ">
        <ul id="primary-menu-hidden " class="menu ">
            <li id="menu-item-23 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-23 "><a href=" ">Главная</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-27 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-10 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-27 "><a href=" ">Меню2</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu ">
                        <li id="menu-item-163 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-163 "><a href=" ">Подменю1</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-164 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-164 "><a href=" ">Подменю2</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-165 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-165 "><a href=" ">Подменю3</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-166 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-166 "><a href=" ">Подменю4</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-167 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-167 "><a href=" ">Подменю5</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-168 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-168 "><a href=" ">Подменю6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li id="menu-item-29 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29 "><a href=" ">Меню3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-28 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28 "><a href=" ">Меню4</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-30 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30 "><a href=" ">Меню5</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-26 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26 "><a href=" ">Меню6</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-24 " class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24 "><a href=" ">Меню7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно что у вас происходит.
Для начала я бы рекомендовал сделать переключение с помощью метода toggle

```
  jQuery('.hidden_menu .menu-item-27 a').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery('.sub-menu').toggle()
  });
```

А дальше необходимо навешивать дополнительные события и делать те действия, которые вам необходимо.